# Change Double format - dot to comma

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I must change Double format from dot to comma. I try this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,00",
                   DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY)); 
selectedSheet.addCell(new Number(selectedCellColumn, 
                                 selectedCellRow,
                                 Double.valueOf(df.format(value)));
```

but it`s not working. Have you got any ideas how you can change a dot to a comma?

Comment: Why do you use `Double.valueOf` in your `System.out.println` command? This way, you do not print the formatted string.

Comment: just remove the `Double.valueOf`.

Comment: I`m sorry, I put in a bad line. I edited the post

Comment: A `Double` does not have a format. It's just a number. The format belongs only to the `String` representation of that number. So whatever you do, don't call `Double.valueOf`. It seems what you really need to do is forget about using `DecimalFormat` and instead tell your spreadsheet cell to display values in your desired format.

Comment: Please update your question to make more clear that this is about an Excel library.

Comment: @C.Champagne: Why is this tagged `apache poi`? There is no `apache poi` code anywhere in the question. The `selectedSheet.addCell` sounds more like `jexcelapi`.

Comment: @AxelRichter you are probably correct, so I changed the tag to your suggestion (I didn't wait to C.Champagne to get back). Now, I think the answer to this question is to use jexcelapi classes WritableCellFormat and NumberFormat. The OP should look these up.

Comment: @AxelRichter You seem to be right sorry. I felt in the same trap than those mentioning Apache POI in their answer. I must admit I didn't know the existence of JExcel API

Answer (score 2):

For (i guess) ApachePOI library to set a different CellUnitStyle use this:

```java
CellStyle unitStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
unitStyle.setDataFormat((short) BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00"));
cell.setCellValue(value);
cell.setCellStyle(unit);
```

Following Formats are builtin available:
[ApachePOI builtin Formats](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html)

Comment: Good answer but alas it seems the OP is probably not using poi but is using jexcelapi.

Comment: Jep, sadly the OP did not come back for long time, so it was a bit of guessing which library he is using. Should i remove my answer, because its not targeting the correct library?

Comment: I think it's still a good answer because the same principle applies: irrespective of API, you need to define the cell format. The jexcelapi will use differently-named methods but the end result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`new Number()` - I assume this takes double as the third argument? In that case, formatting the double value before you pass it in there is  impossible, you need to set the format on how the sheet will display numbers in the cell formatting settings.

Or is the problem that you have a string like "5,3" and want to convert it to double? It looks like the varaible `value` already has a double value in it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a symbol table in the java doc of `DecimalFormat`:

```
Symbol   Location    Localized?    Meaning
------------------------------------------
0        Number      Yes           Digit
#        Number      Yes           Digit, zero shows as absent
.        Number      Yes           Decimal separator or monetary decimal separator
-        Number      Yes           Minus sign
,        Number      Yes           Grouping separator
etc...
```

You were using the grouping separator `,` but you wanted to use the decimal separator `.`, so change your string from `#,00` to `#.00`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
String format = df.format(3.23456);
System.out.println(format); // prints 3,23
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
double value = 123.12345;
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###", decimalFormatSymbols);
System.out.println(df.format(value));
selectedSheet.addCell(new Number(selectedCellColumn, selectedCellRow, Double.valueOf(df.format(value)));
```

Output :

```
123,123
```